# Medium editor with Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, editor

I have added editable class to my `f.text_area` and then calling the editor for that class. I want to fix the height `(row=10)` for my text area which is not working when i give it the editable class.
can someone help me with this? Or suggest another editor like medium one but that can style a `text_area`?

my code:

```
    <%= f.text_area :story, :class => 'form-control', rows: 10 , id:'editable' %>
```

script:

```
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('#editable'),
editor = new MediumEditor(elements, {
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the medium editor styling options in that hash after elements. See details about how to style it here: https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor#mediumeditor-options

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a `<textarea>` element into MediumEditor, it will hide the `<textarea>` and create a `<div contenteditable="true">` which will be editable and act like a WYSIWYG editor so you can see the formatting as you type (ie bold, italic, underline, bullets, etc.).  MediumEditor will monitor the `<div>` for any changes and make sure they are sync'd into the hidden `<textarea>`.

When it hides the `<textarea>` and inserts the `<div>` it copies most of the attributes from the `<textarea>` into the `<div>`.  So, if you add a classname to your textarea (ie `<textarea class="editor">`) that class will be copied into the created `<div>`.

Then, you can style the editor however you'd like:

```
div.editor {
    line-height: 12px;
    height: 120px;
}
```

Normally, the `<div>` would auto-size as the user types, but you can restrict the height via css if you'd like.